# Python: How to open a file and comment a particular line?

Tags: python

Is there a way to open a file (let's say a .py file) and comment a particular line already existent in the file?
Or is there a way to create a piece of code that replaces that line with another one?

Comment: Yes there is, have you tried something ?

Comment: welcome to SO! you should show your own code effort and if necessary seek debugging help here, also best to include a minimal example to make the question completely clear

Comment: check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just read in the file line by line and then append to an output file the lines either with or without a comment, depending on your needs.

For example to add the comment on each line starting with the string `abc` you could do:

```
with open('in.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            if line.startswith('abc'):
                outfile.write(line.strip() + " # Here's abc\n")
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
```

This would make:

```
abc 1 # Here's abc
blabla 2
def 3
abc 4 # Here's abc
```

from the input file:

```
abc 1
blabla 2
def 3
abc 4
```

The check wether a line needs commented can also be searching by regex or by modifying my example a bit you could comment also certain line numbers. But that's up to you now to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can open a file and read it line by line as,

```
with open('file.py') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Search for the particular line as raw string or regular expression with an if condition and replace it like,

```
for n, line in enumerate(lines):
    if(line == search_line):
        lines[n] = new_line
```

Write to the same file like:

```
with open('file.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python solution that takes a file called `commentFile.py` and comments out any line containing the string `comment`.

```
wfile = open("commentFile.py","r+")

d = wfile.readlines()
wfile.seek(0)
allLines = []

for line in d:
    if("comment" in line and "#" not in line):
        allLines.append("#"+line)
    else:
        allLines.append(line)
wfile.writelines(allLines)
wfile.close()
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would include your reasoning behind your code and also additional assumptions put into it (like the line to be commented is the only line containing "comment")